# Is there a Flutter package to read data from email?

Tags: flutter, email, dart, flutter-packages

I am planning to build an app that will read parcel delivery notifications from the user's email account.

Is there a Flutter package which allows me to read data from email apps or even email accounts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are multiple ones.

Just [search for imap on pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages?q=imap).

The Internet Message Access Protocol **(IMAP)** is an Internet standard protocol **used by email clients to retrieve email messages from a mail server** over a TCP/IP connection. (source: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Message_Access_Protocol))